how to avoid soft deleted items in relations with find in postgres and TypeORM?
i dont want to get the soft deleted items from relations when i find any object. how to do it?
const product = await this.productRepository.findOne({
    where: {
       id: productId,
    },
    relations: [
       'items',
       'billingAddress',
       'shippingAddress',
       'contact',
       'tax',
       'paymentTerm',
       'transactions',
       'salesPerson',
    ],
 });

here i soft deleted a transaction, but when i am trying to find the product, i am getting the soft deleted transaction too, what i can do to avoid?

I tried and found out this is a default behaviour. I just have to put deletedAt column in the entity with the @DeleteDateColumn attribute.
@DeleteDateColumn({ nullable: true })
deletedAt:Date

and the relation doesn't join the column having deletedAt not null.
